# Custom Home Screen with the properties like default Home Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-relativelayout

i a designing an home screen.in this,i am showing the system icons in Grid view.But I have a problem that my icons are scrollable vertically.Here,i want to make these icons scrollable in horizontal direction.
I have used,
Scroll view and horizontal scroll view to get this result but failed.
I whole project, i am using relative layouts.

and for my Grid view,

```
</RelativeLayout>

<GridView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android 4.x stock home screen uses a series of `GridView` widgets in a `ViewPager`, near as I can tell. You might be able to tell more by using Hierarchy View or **`uiautomatorviewer`** to inspect the UI of home screen.